# Import a library into Android/Java program without using Eclipse

Tags: android, andengine

I want to know how to import a custom library into my Android/Java program. I want to develop with AndEngine but I don't know how to import libraries manually. :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I import an Android library and use it in both production code and tests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153101/how-do-i-import-an-android-library-and-use-it-in-both-production-code-and-tests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Maven for create android app. Install with maven your lib and add it as dependency in pom.xml

then try to build it with maven.

Comment: I build my Android with Apache Ant :P

Comment: So if you are using Ant and you don;t want to switch to Maven try to google how to add external lib into ant build.xml... one of first results: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651423/add-user-libraries-to-ant-builder-classpath

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  Add the Lib folder on your project. On that folder you should placed your jar files.
```

After that, Right click on your project and choose the buildpath from appeared menu. There's you can see,

```
   libraries tab->Add Jars->please goes to your project Lib folder(created by you)->jar files.
```